# Comparing Floats in a dataframe and then running a script on any rows that match

Tags: python

With this script I am attempting to find addresses in a data frame that fall within both 0.01 of latitude and 0.01 of longitude. That data frame looks like this:

```
                     Address     State    ZipCode        Lat       Long
0  123 Main St New York          New York 14787          42.320889 -79.573733
1  896 Smith Ave New York        NY       14787          42.319874 -79.571941
2  40 E Main St, New York        Ny       14787          42.323447 -79.574977
3  123 Main Street New York      New York 14787          42.321889 -79.573933
```

In order to compare latitudes and longitudes of each address I have created the following loop to iterate through each Latitude and prints a list of all Latitudes within 0.01 of each other. However, I need to also loop through longitudes and have a combination that only returns values that fall within 0.01 of both latitude and longitude. After this I would run a comparison algorithm on any two addresses that fall within the 0.01 threshold of both lat and long.

```
for i in df['Lat']:
    for j in df['Lat']:
        if i == j:
            continue
        elif (i - 0.01) <= j <= (i + 0.01):
            print(str(i) +" and "+ str(j))
```

prints:

```
42.32088914 and 42.31987373
42.32088914 and 42.32344741
42.32088914 and 42.32188914
42.31987373 and 42.32088914
42.31987373 and 42.32344741
42.31987373 and 42.32188914
42.32344741 and 42.32088914
42.32344741 and 42.31987373
42.32344741 and 42.32188914
42.32188914 and 42.32088914
42.32188914 and 42.31987373
42.32188914 and 42.32344741
```

Comment: If you want to cluster your data on floating point pairs, e.g. geo locations, you should have a look at `scipy.spatial.KDTree` or directly look into the methods provided by `sklearn.cluster`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Address': [
         '123 Main St New York ',
         '896 Smith Ave New York',
         '40 E Main St, New York',
         '123 Main Street New York'],
     'State': ['New York', 'NY', 'Ny', 'New York'],
     'ZipCode': ['14787', '14787', '14787', '14787'],
     'Lat': [42.320889, 42.319874, 42.323447, 42.321889],
     'Long': [-79.573733, -79.573733, -79.574977, -79.573933]})

# keep list paired address already identified: all pairs will be matched twice
processed = set()

for idx, r in df.iterrows():
     # for each row in main dataframe, filter to properties
     # within 0.01 degrees lon/lat, which are not that property
     matches = df[
         (np.abs(df.Lat - r.Lat) <= 0.01) &
         (np.abs(df.Long - r.Long) <= 0.01) &
         (df.index != idx)
        ]
     for idx_match, r_match in matches.iterrows():
         key = tuple(sorted((idx, idx_match)))
         if not key in processed:
             processed.add(key)
             print((idx, idx_match), (r.Lat, r.Long), (r_match.Lat, r_match.Long))
             # do stuff here with matches
```

Comment: This code worked great. Is it possible to compare the string addresses associated with each matched pair with this output? For example for the match (0,1) is it possible to associated these with the string addresses in a further step?

Comment: you can access the two addresses as `r.Address` and `r_match.Address` in the `do stuff here` section. I'm not sure what you mean by associate these with the string addresses.